How to extrude, bridge or in some other way fill this part out

I was following along with a tutorial and the video jumps past how he did this portion. I figured out to mirror the arch with a Mirror Modify, but beyond that I'm lost. I could apply the modify and then use a Bridge Edge Loops to get a semi-close effect but it's not the one in the video and I'd really like to know how to do it
Here's what the one in the video looked like. Apologies the question isn't more specific. I'm not new to blender but it's been a long time. Something else of note is the red line bisecting portions of the handle in the screenshot of his video that I don't have.


Since you mention "extrude" already in the question, did you try that? To me it seems - without knowing the video - that he took the boundary edge of the general shape and extruded it twice with E. Or extruded it once the whole distance and then cut it with a Loop Cut using Ctrl+R. The red edge shows that he marked it as seam, but that has nothing with modeling the visible shape. This is for creating the UV map. And why on Earth is the tutor naked in the video? :D

@GordonBrinkmann good question on the nakedness lol. Here's the video: https://youtu.be/lPGjxkCXoZA?si=AsJg4rz46OgBvvZn. The jump is at 6:00-6:15 or so. As for extruding, I did try but I can't get the extrusion to lay cleanly against the existing geometry.

Usually one would use the Clipping option in the Mirror modifier to make sure it stops at the mirror axis, but the option is disabled in his modifier as it seems. Or if the origin point of the object is on the 3D Cursor and he used this as Transform Pivot Point, he could have used S X 0 to scale to 0 on the X axis which in this case scales all down to X = 0 on the cursor. He has set the 3D Cursor as pivot point so this could be the case here. But this is pure speculation since there is absolutely nothing to see, obviously he does not care about making it beginner friendly.

@GordonBrinkmann yeah in the comments when someone pointed out he skipped some bits, he said "Unfortunate" and left it at that. What would you recommend I do?

Watch tutorials from people that actually try to teach you something even if you are not already highly skilled. I know it is hard when you want to model an assault rifle that beginner tutorials only model "boring" stuff, but what he did there or the hints I gave at what he might be doing, this should not be too complicated. If you google "blender mirror modifier" on YT there are tons of tutorials that teach you the basics of how to use it. As I said before: either scale to the cursor if it is on the mirror axis or use extrude while the Clipping option is enabled in the modifier.
